# How can I make position fixed for span under li

Tags: html, css

The arrow icon besides Room 1 is a span . The code for this arrow-icon is

```
<span class="showActionMenu"></span>
```

This span is under "li" tag.The problem is the text you can see "1-02-Sudhansu PromptPackage" is not too large this time.So the arrow-icon besides it is at the right place.But if I increase the text size then the arrow-icon shifts down as the "span" that i am using is just after this text in the code.I want this arrow-icon should always be at that very place means to the extreme right of the text .No matter how long the text is , the arrow-icon should not be relative to the text-size.Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I cannot add image .Can somebody please help .I can post this in a better way so that you guyz can understand my query.

Comment: When you edit your post there is a small image button in the editing tools. CLick on that and choose your image

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in which you reproduce the problem? Eventually you can add a link to your image.

Comment: @singe31 I did this but i was aborted to do so as i need 10 reputation minimum for adding images . I am new here .

Comment: I think SO should allow users to add Images even if they are new. Why it doesn't??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position` to place the span to the right of its parent:

```css
li {
  width: 180px;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

span.showActionMenu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<li>This is my text <span class="showActionMenu"></span></li>
```